# OLAP Cube Parallelism not working as expected

Tags: sql, ssas, sql-server-2014, olap-cube

We are having a OLAP SSAS cube setup and the Cube Processing is triggered from SQL Server Agent Job (on  SQL Server 2014). The SQL Server Agent Job step is as below:

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
   <Parallel MaxParallel="3">
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>{DatabaseID}</DatabaseID>
        <CubeID>{CubeName}</CubeID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

This step is supposed to trigger three parallel measure pull call from the SQL Server databases. But what we could see is it is triggering 10 parallel select queries to the Database. There are few other cubes which has similar parallel settings and fire only 3 queries at a time. The issue of 10 calls are happening only in case of this cube and is happening only in one specific environment. Is there any settings at SSAS cube level which overrides the parallel setting set by the SQL Agent Job?

Answer (score 0):

I think the setting you want is: `Maximum Number of Connections` in the Data Souce.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/set-data-source-properties-ssas-multidimensional?view=asallproducts-allversions

> Specifies the maximum number of connections allowed by Analysis Services to connect to the data source. If more connections are needed, Analysis Services will wait until a connection becomes available. The default is 10. Constraining the number of connections ensures that the external data source is not overloaded with Analysis Services requests.

[image]

The `maxParallel` attribute for `Parallel` element controls the number of processing threads.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/xmla/xml-elements-properties/parallel-element-xmla?view=asallproducts-allversions

> Indicates the maximum number of threads on which to run commands in parallel. If not specified or set to 0, the instance of Analysis Services determines an optimal number of threads based on the number of processors available on the computer.

Comment: this setting is set as 10 for the DataSource in all the environment. But, this is happening only for one cube and only in one specific environment.